# Match last dir before filename in unix path

Tags: regex

I need to find the regex to extract the last dir before the file in full path strings like these:

```
./Resources/views/product/edit.html.twig
./Resources/views/product/show.html.twig
./Resources/views/product/new.html.twig
```

So these strings always yield 'product'.

Comment: What tool are you using? Can you use capturing groups or does it need to be the entire regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
([^/]+)/[^/]*$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/No5EDy/1).
Broken apart, this says:

```
([^/]+) # capture anything not a /, at least once
/       # a /
[^/]*   # 0+ not /
$       # end of the line
```

Depending on the actual language and/or delimiters used, you may need to escape the forward slashes to `\/`.